# How can I print the requests in boost.asio?

Tags: c++, networking, boost-asio

I'm using `boost.asio` to write a simple server. The code below is trying to do 2 things:

1. print the request
2. respond to the client `hello`

but it does not.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main(){
    
        try{
    
                boost::asio::io_context ioc;
                tcp::acceptor acceptor(ioc, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 1010));
                for(;;){
                        tcp::socket socket(ioc);
                        acceptor.accept(socket);
                        boost::system::error_code err;
                        std::string buff;
                        socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buff), err);
                        std::cout << buff << '\n';
                        boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer("hello"),err);
    
                }   
        }   
        catch (std::exception& e){ 
    
                std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        }   

        return 0;

}
```

When I run the server and send a request using `curl` it does not respond and only print an empty line.

```sh
[amirreza@localhost ~]$ curl 127.0.0.1:1010
curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed

[amirreza@localhost ~]$
```

and in server side (2 empty line):

```sh
[amirreza@localhost 2]$ sudo ./server 
[sudo] password for amirreza:
```

here I have 2 questions:

- why server doesn't print the curl request?
- why curl doesn't receive the `hello` message?

I also observed packets sent and received between server and curl in wireshark. At first the tcp handshake will occur but when curl send the `HTTP` request, the server respond a tcp packet with `RST` flag to reset the connection.

Comment: You never check the return value of `write()`.  Do that.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I just checked the return value of `write()`, it was 6, does it help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First thing I notice:

   ```
   std::string buff;
   socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buff), err);
   ```

   This reads into an empty string: 0 bytes. Either reserve space:

   ```
   buff.resize(1024);
   socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buff), err);
   ```

   or use a dynamic buffer with a composed read operation (see next)
2. read_some reads whatever is available, not necessarily a line. see `read_until` for higher level read operations

   ```
   std::string buff;
   read_until(socket, boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(buff), "\n");
   ```
3. handle errors. In your case you could simply remove the `ec` variable, and rely on exceptions since you alreaady handle those

### Fixes

```
#include <boost/asio/buffer.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main(){
    try{
        boost::asio::io_context ioc;
        tcp::acceptor acceptor(ioc, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(),  11010));
        for(;;) {
            tcp::socket socket(ioc);
            acceptor.accept(socket);
            std::string buff;
            auto bytes = read_until(socket, boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(buff), "\n");
            std::cout << buff.substr(0, bytes) << std::flush;
            boost::asio::write(socket,  boost::asio::buffer("hello"));
        }   
    }   
    catch (std::exception const& e){ 
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }   
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, do you know why still my curl does not show the server response? in this case `hello`

Comment: Curl expects a HTTP server. Simplest thing that might work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/397242355895f3d7 Also, make sure you don't print binary data (you send "hello\0") so curl prints it (or use `--output -` to try anyways)

Comment: To actually parse/write valid HTTP requests/respone, why don't you use Boost Beast? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77523ba8f77df287

Comment: I'm not sure, but even the message `hello` is not shown in wireshark.